# No java installations was detected, although I have Java

Tags: terminal, java

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)

$ which java
/usr/bin/java

$ ls /usr/libexec/java_home
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

But when I run some application from the terminal, is says in terminal:

```
No java installations was detected.
Please go to http://www.java.com/getjava/ and download
```

Comment: I had the same situation and concluded the runtime environment is different than the full Java suite. Can anyone confirm this? That app probably needs the full Java program, current version is 1.8.*. Also, some programs need a version greater than 1.6

Comment: did you try this http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp or this http://javatester.org/

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533528/installing-java-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks

Answer (score 1):

I had such problem in `sbt` run having `$GREP_OPTIONS=--color=always --ignore-case`. Unsetting the environment variable helped.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47180447/907576